# Getters \ setters for dummies

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

I've been trying to get my head around getters and setters and its not sinking in. I've read [JavaScript Getters and Setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) and [Defining Getters and Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide:Creating_New_Objects:Defining_Getters_and_Setters) and just not getting it.

Can someone clearly state:

1. What a getter and setter are meant to do, and
2. Give some VERY simple examples?

Comment: Personally, I don't know how you can get a clearer explanation than John's...

Comment: Basically I see it like this: you're defining overloads for getting and setting the property, and these overloads are functions; but, you don't have to call them. This way you can replace `a = setValue(5);` with `a = 5;` and `setValue()` would thereby be called under the hood to do whatever you like.

Answer (score 106):

In addition to [@millimoose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies-meaning-me/812985#812985), setters can also be used to update other values.

```
function Name(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

Name.prototype = {
    get fullName() {
        return this.first + " " + this.last;
    },

    set fullName(name) {
        var names = name.split(" ");
        this.first = names[0];
        this.last = names[1];
    }
};
```

Now, you can set `fullName`, and `first` and `last` will be updated and vice versa.

```
n = new Name('Claude', 'Monet')
n.first # "Claude"
n.last # "Monet"
n.fullName # "Claude Monet"
n.fullName = "Gustav Klimt"
n.first # "Gustav"
n.last # "Klimt"
```

Comment: @Akash: No, although, Internet Explorer 9 does support the newer `Object.defineProperty` function that can define getters and setters.

Comment: Isnt it really painful that MS does not support JS correctly and they do not make their silverlight run everywhere, so I have to program everything twice, one for SL and one for rest of the world :)

Comment: How do you make first and last private?

Comment: @Martin: You could make them private by using the same technique as in [John's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies/813227#813227). If you want to use real getters/setters, you would have to use `this.__defineGetter__` or the newer `Object.defineProperty` function.

Comment: Only one problem with approach listed above, if you want to add getters and setters for already existing class it will override prototypes, and original methods will not be accessible.

Comment: Doesn't this approach overwrite `Name.prototype.constructor`? Seems like a bad alternative to [millimoose's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/812985/1707123).

Comment: @MatthewCrumley Is this es6 syntax?

Comment: @Jessica Yes, although it was actually introduced in ES5.

Answer (score 64):

## Getters and Setters in JavaScript

### Overview

Getters and setters in JavaScript are used for defining *computed properties*, or *accessors*. A computed property is one that uses a function to get or set an object value. The basic theory is doing something like this:

```
var user = { /* ... object with getters and setters ... */ };
user.phone = '+1 (123) 456-7890'; // updates a database
console.log( user.areaCode ); // displays '123'
console.log( user.area ); // displays 'Anytown, USA'
```

This is useful for automatically doing things behind-the-scenes when a property is accessed, like keeping numbers in range, reformatting strings, triggering value-has-changed events, updating relational data, providing access to private properties, and more.

The examples below show the basic syntax, though they simply get and set the internal object value without doing anything special. In real-world cases you would modify the input and/or output value to suit your needs, as noted above.

### get/set Keywords

ECMAScript 5 supports `get` and `set` keywords for defining computed properties. They work with all modern browsers except IE 8 and below.

```
var foo = {
    bar : 123,
    get bar(){ return bar; },
    set bar( value ){ this.bar = value; }
};
foo.bar = 456;
var gaz = foo.bar;
```

### Custom Getters and Setters

`get` and `set` aren't reserved words, so they can be overloaded to create your own custom, cross-browser computed property functions. This will work in any browser.

```
var foo = {
    _bar : 123,
    get : function( name ){ return this[ '_' + name ]; },
    set : function( name, value ){ this[ '_' + name ] = value; }
};
foo.set( 'bar', 456 );
var gaz = foo.get( 'bar' );
```

Or for a more compact approach, a single function may be used.

```
var foo = {
    _bar : 123,
    value : function( name /*, value */ ){
        if( arguments.length < 2 ){ return this[ '_' + name ]; }
        this[ '_' + name ] = value;
    }
};
foo.value( 'bar', 456 );
var gaz = foo.value( 'bar' );
```

Avoid doing something like this, which can lead to code bloat.

```
var foo = {
    _a : 123, _b : 456, _c : 789,
    getA : function(){ return this._a; },
    getB : ..., getC : ..., setA : ..., setB : ..., setC : ...
};
```

For the above examples, the internal property names are abstracted with an underscore in order to discourage users from simply doing `foo.bar` vs. `foo.get( 'bar' )` and getting an "uncooked" value. You can use conditional code to do different things depending on the name of the property being accessed (via the `name` parameter).

### Object.defineProperty()

Using `Object.defineProperty()` is another way to add getters and setters, and can be used on objects after they're defined. It can also be used to set configurable and enumerable behaviors. This syntax also works with IE 8, but unfortunately only on DOM objects.

```
var foo = { _bar : 123 };
Object.defineProperty( foo, 'bar', {
    get : function(){ return this._bar; },
    set : function( value ){ this._bar = value; }
} );
foo.bar = 456;
var gaz = foo.bar;
```

### __defineGetter__()

Finally, `__defineGetter__()` is another option. It's deprecated, but still widely used around the web and thus unlikely to disappear anytime soon. It works on all browsers except IE 10 and below. Though the other options also work well on non-IE, so this one isn't that useful.

```
var foo = { _bar : 123; }
foo.__defineGetter__( 'bar', function(){ return this._bar; } );
foo.__defineSetter__( 'bar', function( value ){ this._bar = value; } );
```

Also worth noting is that in the latter examples, the internal names must be different than the accessor names to avoid recursion (ie, `foo.bar` calling `foo.get(bar)` calling `foo.bar` calling `foo.get(bar)`...).

### See Also

MDN [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), 
[Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), [__defineGetter__()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__), [__defineSetter__()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineSetter__)
MSDN
[IE8 Getter Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd229916%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: In the **more compact approach**, `this[ '_' + name ] = value;` could be `this[ '_' + name ] = arguments[1];` and there would be no need to specify `value` arg.

Comment: The example: 
````var foo = {
    bar : 123,
    get bar(){ return bar; },
    set bar( value ){ this.bar = value; }
};
foo.bar = 456;
````
Raises an exception:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.set bar [as bar] (<anonymous>:4:32)
    at Object.set bar [as bar] (<anonymous>:4:32)
    at Object.set bar [as bar] (<anonymous>:4:32)
    at Object.set bar [as bar] (<anonymous>:4:32)
    at Object.set bar [as bar] (<anonymous>:4:32)
    at Object.set bar [as bar] (<anonymous>:4:32)

Comment: The set/get name must be different to the property name. So instead of ```bar: 123``` and ```this.bar = value``` etc. change these to ```_bar ``` for example.
See: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/getters-setters-javascript/

Comment: @nevf Thanks for the correction! Yes, typically with computed properties the "real" internal one is named like `_foo` or `mFoo`. If it's the same as the getter/setter, it will cause an infinite loop due to recursion and then a Stack Overflow™ ;-) because when you say a = b, it calls a.get(b) which itself calls a = b, which calls a.get(b), ...

Answer (score 59):

You'd use them for instance to implement computed properties.

For example:

```
function Circle(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}

Object.defineProperty(Circle.prototype, 'circumference', {
    get: function() { return 2*Math.PI*this.radius; }
});

Object.defineProperty(Circle.prototype, 'area', {
    get: function() { return Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius; }
});

c = new Circle(10);
console.log(c.area); // Should output 314.159
console.log(c.circumference); // Should output 62.832
```

<sup>[(CodePen)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HJigF?editors=101)</sup>

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get it.

I'm trying to assign a getter to the length property of an array object but getting an error:
    
    "Redeclaration of var length"

And the code looks like this:

    obj = [];
    obj.__defineGetter__('length',function(){
        return this.length;
    });

Comment: That's because Array objects already have a builtin length property. If the redeclaration was allowed, calling the new length would recurse infinitely. Try calling the property "my_length" or some such.

Comment: In order to define both getters in one statement, use [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).

Comment: Can't you just make { "area": function () {return ...} } ? simply assign it as an object property

Comment: @developer That’s not a Javascript getter as defined by the language, that’s just a function. You have to call it to get the value, it doesn’t overload access to the property. Also there’s a special circle of hell reserved for people who invent their own broken object systems in JS instead of building on the one it already has.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry to resurrect an old question, but I thought I might contribute a couple of very basic examples and for-dummies explanations.  None of the other answers posted thusfar illustrate syntax like the [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)'s first example, which is about as basic as one can get.

**Getter:**

```
var settings = {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Smith',
    get fullname() { return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname; }
};

console.log(settings.fullname);
```

... will log `John Smith`, of course.  A *getter* behaves like a variable object property, but offers the flexibility of a function to calculate its returned value on the fly.  It's basically a fancy way to create a function that doesn't require () when calling.

**Setter:**

```
var address = {
    set raw(what) {
        var loc = what.split(/\s*;\s*/),
        area = loc[1].split(/,?\s+(\w{2})\s+(?=\d{5})/);

        this.street = loc[0];
        this.city = area[0];
        this.state = area[1];
        this.zip = area[2];
    }
};

address.raw = '123 Lexington Ave; New York NY  10001';
console.log(address.city);
```

... will log `New York` to the console.  Like getters, *setters* are called with the same syntax as setting an object property's value, but are yet another fancy way to call a function without ().

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calraith/dybsLm5L/) for a more thorough, perhaps more practical example.  Passing values into the object's *setter* triggers the creation or population of other object items.  Specifically, in the jsfiddle example, passing an array of numbers prompts the setter to calculate mean, median, mode, and range; then sets object properties for each result.

Comment: I still don't understand the benefit of using get and set vs creating a  getMethod or setMethod. Is the only benefit that you can call it without () ? There must be another reason it's added to javascript.

Comment: @Andreas Getters and setters behave like properties when called, which can help articulate their intended purpose. They don't unlock otherwise missing abilities, but their use can help you organize your thoughts. That's the real benefit. As a practical example, I used to use a getter to extend a Google Maps object. I needed to calculate the camera roll angle so I could rotate map tiles flat to the horizon. Google does this automatically on the back end now; but at the time it was helpful to me to retrieve `maps.roll` as a property rather than `maps.roll()`'s return val. It's just a preference.

Comment: so it's just syntactic sugar to make code look cleaner without the (). I can't see why you couldn't your example with `maps.roll()`

Comment: @Andreas Who says I couldn't? Like I say, it's just a way to help me keep my thoughts organized. Coding is an art. You don't ask Bob Ross why he had to use burnt ochre when he could've used orange. You may not see a need now, but one day when you decide your painting needs a little burnt ochre, it'll be on your palette.

Comment: :) one thing that i see that get and set syntax does, is being auto-run if it's used as a property of a property.

Answer (score 12):

Getters and setters really only make sense when you have private properties of classes.  Since Javascript doesn't really have private class properties as you would normally think of from Object Oriented Languages, it can be hard to understand.  Here is one example of a private counter object.   The nice thing about this object is that the internal variable "count" cannot be accessed from outside the object.

```
var counter = function() {
    var count = 0;

    this.inc = function() {
        count++;
    };

    this.getCount = function() {
        return count;
    };
};

var i = new Counter();
i.inc();
i.inc();
// writes "2" to the document
document.write( i.getCount());
```

If you are still confused, take a look at Crockford's article on [Private Members in Javascript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: I disagree. Getters and setters are also very useful for encapsulating information whose definition may not just be a simple variable. It can be handy if you need to change the behavior of a system that previously used simple properties and which other things may depend on. Furthermore, your example only demonstrates "pseudo getters" which are just functions. Real JavaScript getters *appear* as simple values (and are accessed without function notation), hence the real power of them.

Comment: Not sure if I would call that powerful. Something *appearing* as X but is really Y is not necessarily clear.

I would absolutely NOT expect `var baz = foo.bar` to have a full blown set of hidden behavior behind it. I *would* expect that from `foo.getBar()`, however.

Answer (score 8):

I think the first article you link to states it pretty clearly:

> The obvious advantage to writing JavaScript in this manner is that you can use it obscure values that you don't want the user to directly access.

The goal here is to encapsulate and abstract away the fields by only allowing access to them thru a `get()` or `set()` method. This way, you can store the field/data internally in whichever way you want, but outside components are only away of your published interface. This allows you to make internal changes without changing external interfaces, to do some validation or error-checking within the `set()` method, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Although often we are used to seeing objects with public properties without any access
control, JavaScript allows us to accurately describe properties. In fact, we can use
descriptors in order to control how a property can be accessed and which logic we can
apply to it. Consider the following example:

```
var employee = {
    first: "Boris",
    last: "Sergeev",
    get fullName() {
        return this.first + " " + this.last;
    },
    set fullName(value) {
        var parts = value.toString().split(" ");
        this.first = parts[0] || "";
        this.last = parts[1] || "";
    },
    email: "boris.sergeev@example.com"
};
```

The final result:

```
console.log(employee.fullName); //Boris Sergeev
employee.fullName = "Alex Makarenko";

console.log(employee.first);//Alex
console.log(employee.last);//Makarenko
console.log(employee.fullName);//Alex Makarenko
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define instance method for js class, via prototype of the constructor.

Following is the sample code:

```
// BaseClass

var BaseClass = function(name) {
    // instance property
    this.name = name;
};

// instance method
BaseClass.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
};
BaseClass.prototype.setName = function(name) {
    return this.name = name;
};


// test - start
function test() {
    var b1 = new BaseClass("b1");
    var b2 = new BaseClass("b2");
    console.log(b1.getName());
    console.log(b2.getName());

    b1.setName("b1_new");
    console.log(b1.getName());
    console.log(b2.getName());
}

test();
// test - end
```

And, this should work for any browser, you can also simply use nodejs to run this code.

Comment: This is just creating new getName, and setName methods. These are not related to create property!

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the concept of accessors, then the simple goal is to hide the underlying storage from arbitrary manipulation.  The most extreme mechanism for this is

```
function Foo(someValue) {
    this.getValue = function() { return someValue; }
    return this;
}

var myFoo = new Foo(5);
/* We can read someValue through getValue(), but there is no mechanism
 * to modify it -- hurrah, we have achieved encapsulation!
 */
myFoo.getValue();
```

If you're referring to the actual JS getter/setter feature, eg. `defineGetter`/`defineSetter`, or `{ get Foo() { /* code */ } }`, then it's worth noting that in most modern engines subsequent usage of those properties will be much much slower than it would otherwise be.  eg. compare performance of

```
var a = { getValue: function(){ return 5; }; }
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    a.getValue();
```

vs.

```
var a = { get value(){ return 5; }; }
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    a.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

What's so confusing about it... getters are functions that are called when you get a property, setters, when you set it.
example, if you do

```
obj.prop = "abc";
```

You're setting the property prop, if you're using getters/setters, then the setter function will be called, with "abc" as an argument. 
The setter function definition inside the object would ideally look something like this:

```
set prop(var) {
   // do stuff with var...
}
```

I'm not sure how well that is implemented across browsers. It seems Firefox also has an alternative syntax, with double-underscored special ("magic") methods. As usual Internet Explorer does not support any of this.

Answer (score 2):

I was also somewhat confused by the [explanation I read](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/), because I was trying to add a property to an existing prototype that I did not write, so replacing the prototype seemed like the wrong approach. So, for posterity, here's how I added a `last` property to `Array`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "last", {
    get: function() { return this[this.length - 1] }
});
```

Ever so slightly nicer than adding a function IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `__defineGetter__`:

```js
function Vector2(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Vector2.prototype.__defineGetter__("magnitude", function () {
   return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x+this.y*this.y);
});

console.log(new Vector2(1,1).magnitude)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```js
function Vector2(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.__defineGetter__("magnitude", function () {
       return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x+this.y*this.y);
    });
}



console.log(new Vector2(1,1).magnitude)
```

But this function has been flagged as "legacy" recently, being dropped in favor of `Object.defineProperty()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no example here with ES6 `class` (which is not even 'new' now, it's the norm):

```
class Student {

    contructor(firstName, lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName
        this.lastName = lastName
        this.secretId = Math.random()    
    }
    
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`; // this is backtick in js, u can check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678299/12056841
    }

    set firstName(newFirstName) {
        // validate that newFirstName is a string (and maybe limit length)
        this.firstName = newFirstName
    }

    get studentId() { return this.secretId }
}
```

and **no setter** for secretId because we don't want anyone to change it.

** if `secretId` shouldn't be changed at all, a nice approach is to declare it as 'private' to this **class** by adding a '#' to it
(e.g: `this.#secretId = Math.random()`, and `return this.#secretId`

*Update:* about backing fields
You might need to rename your field - or your setter function but it makes more sense to me to change your field name. One option is like I mentioned above (using a `#` for declaring the field as 'private'). Another way is to just rename it (`_firstName`, `firstName_`...)

Comment: Aren't backing fields required to avoid an stack overflow/ infinite loop?

Comment: They might be -- I haven't really tried using a setter before. I'll update my answer and address that issue

Answer (score -1):

I've got one for you guys that might be a little ugly, but it does get'er done across platforms

```
function myFunc () {

var _myAttribute = "default";

this.myAttribute = function() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) _myAttribute = arguments[0];
    return _myAttribute;
}
}
```

this way, when you call

```
var test = new myFunc();
test.myAttribute(); //-> "default"
test.myAttribute("ok"); //-> "ok"
test.myAttribute(); //-> "ok"
```

If you really want to spice things up.. you can insert a typeof check:

```
if (arguments.length > 0 && typeof arguments[0] == "boolean") _myAttribute = arguments[0];
if (arguments.length > 0 && typeof arguments[0] == "number") _myAttribute = arguments[0];
if (arguments.length > 0 && typeof arguments[0] == "string") _myAttribute = arguments[0];
```

or go even crazier with the advanced typeof check: [type.of() code at codingforums.com](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=105653)

Comment: the point was to be able to change an attribute to something fancier without needing to change the public interface.  Adding a call () tag changes it.