# javascript object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can we create a class with getters and setters and an array of objects of this class using javascript?

Comment: Yes. Why isn't it working for you? Perhaps you could post some code.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is not a class based object oriented language. However we can mimic this behavior. [This](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) article is about implementing private variables but it may help you to design this class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like reflection.