# Javascript overloading dot

Tags: javascript

Hi is there a way to overload the '.'(dot) and [] operator in javascript. ie if I say obj.Name  or obj['Name'] it should call a common method in the obj class by passing Name as argument. The similar kind of functionality available in python using property method. But here I want the ".Name" to be passed as argument to the common method.

like this..

```
function Data(){
    this.getValue(name){
        return '...'
    }
}

data = new Data()
name = data.Name 
name = data['Name']
//both should call data.getValue()
```

Comment: FYI, things have changed since the question was asked. I've [updated my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4569315/157247).

Answer (score 16):

**Answer in 2010**: *(see below for a 2013 update)*

No, you can't redirect property name lookups to your own function.

**However**, as of ECMAScript5, you can define properties with "getters" and "setters". This is a new feature which isn't widely-supported yet, but when it is, it will do something *vaguely* similar. This is covered in a couple of parts of [the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1). So if you defined all of your properties that way, and then sent the actual request to your central `getValue` function, you'd end up with largely what you wanted. Someday. :-) Except that it won't call `getValue` for a property that doesn't exist.

---

**Answer in 2013**:

This is going to change soon (and it [already has](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/) for up-to-date Firefox users): ECMAScript 6th edition will have *proxies*. They're defined in the [draft specification](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts), and also on [this page](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies) (but the spec drafts take precedence).

Proxies let you create objects that are true proxies (facades) for other objects. Here's a simple example that turns any property values that are strings to all caps on retrieval:

```
var original = {"foo": "bar"};
var proxy = new Proxy(original, {
    get: function(target, name, receiver) {
        var rv = target[name];
        if (typeof rv === "string") {
            rv = rv.toUpperCase();
        }
        return rv;
    }
});

console.log("original.foo = " + original.foo); // "bar"
console.log("proxy.foo = " + proxy.foo);       // "BAR"
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/eYAhesa/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/eYAhesa/1/edit)

Operations you don't override have their default behavior. In the above, all we override is `get`, but there's a whole list of operations you can hook into.

In the `get` handler function's arguments list:

- `target` is the object being proxied (`original`, in our case).
- `name` is (of course) the name of the property being retrieved.
- `receiver` is either the proxy itself or something that inherits from it. In our case, `receiver` is `===` `proxy`, but if `proxy` were used as a prototype, `receiver` could be a descendant object, hence it being on the function signature (but at the end, so you can readily leave it off if, as with our example above, you don't actually use it).

This lets you create an object with the catch-all getter and setter feature you want:

```
var obj = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, name) {
        if (!(name in target)) {
            console.log("Getting non-existant property '" + name + "'");
            return undefined;
        }
        return target[name];
    },
    set: function(target, name, value) {
        if (!(name in target)) {
            console.log("Setting non-existant property '" + name + "', initial value: " + value);
        }
        target[name] = value;
    }
});

console.log("[before] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
obj.foo = "bar";
console.log("[after] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/eYAhesa/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/eYAhesa/2/edit) *(Note how I've left `receiver` off the functions, since we don't use it. `receiver` is an optional fourth arg on `set`.)*

The output of the above is:

```
Getting non-existant property 'foo'
[before] obj.foo = undefined
Setting non-existant property 'foo', initial value: bar
[after] obj.foo = bar
```

Note how we get the "non-existant" message when we try to retrieve `foo` when it doesn't yet exist, and again when we create it, but not subsequently.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Thanks. FYI, I noticed the answer was out of date and have just updated it.

Comment: This guy. And his updates. I like this guy and his updates.

Answer (score 2):

On recent JS versions, there is indeed something similar to Python's [properties](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/).

Also see question [Javascript getters and setters for dummies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies)

It may be enough for you, although Python is still way more flexible and compact.

Comment: These aren't the same, they're getters and setters *for a property*, they don't operate on any property.

Comment: +1, but it's very implementation-specific, and it's been outdated by the ECMAScript5 specification, which allows doing that but in a *completely* different way. So support for that syntax (which was *awful*) never really got widespread, and now it certainly won't. But still, for use in a couple of browsers, it's a possibility.

Comment: @Nick: True, but the author could then defer to the central `getValue` function. But only for *defined* properties, no nice catch-all for undefined ones.

Comment: indeed. the question said "using property method" but it should probably be "using __ getattr __ method"

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't overload or replace it in JavaScript.  I wish I had a more comprehensive/informational answer for you...but it just isn't possible, I guess there was never a need seen to add the ability.

Comment: @T.J. - trust me, a *lot* more of my time will be taken up *very* soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this is impossible as operator overloading is impossible in ECMAscript.

If you really need to do this then I would use some preprocessing to convert the parts of code (*and only those that really needs to be instrumented like this*) into instrumented code.

This could easily be done using a little regexp like this

```
var a= "var a = b.c['foo']" // get this via xhr or something
var re = /(\[(.*)\])|(\.([\w\d]+)\b)/g;

var b = a.replace(re, function(m){
    return ".get('" +  m.replace(/[[\].'\"]/g,"") + "')";
});
b; // "var a = b.get('c').get('foo')"

eval(b);
```