# How to wrap or proxy another object in JavaScript in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, wrapper, es6-proxy

I'm doing JavaScript in node.js.

I'm trying wrap an object not yet constructed, allowing calls to any object function and set/get any object attribute through the wrapper, letting the wrapper pass calls/sets/gets to the object if bound in the wrapper or throw an exception if the object is not yet bound in the wrapper. I want to be ignorant to the object. I'm seeking a general purpose mechanism allowing me to wrap any object in this fashion.

I could construct a wrapper structure holding the object

```
wrapper = {
    object: SomeObject
};
```

and address the object through wrapper dereference

```
wrapper.object.someFunction();
```

but I want to be transparent and use the following syntax instead:

```
wrapper.someFunction();
```

I have looked into the Proxy features of ECMAScript 6  but constantly came short on the apply() function trap. Is there a problem with JavaScript V8 and Node.js not being ECMAScript 6 compliant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to overload the "dot "operator, something very familiar to Python guys, the *__getattr__* and *__setattr__* functions.

Indeed, the way to do it in ECMAScript 6 is to use Proxies, and as this post says:

*Proxies let you create objects that are true proxies (facades) for other objects*

[Javascript overloading dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569296/javascript-overloading-dot)

The problem is that NodeJS does not support ECMAScript 6.

So I see two solutions:

1. Why don't you do something a bit idiomatic like, have a function o that will return the object, that way you can do

   ```
   wrapper.o().attribute = ...
   ```
2. Maybe try IO.js that supports ECMAScript 6 and is compatible with Node/npm?