# Javascript overriding the property setting functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js

JavaScript is dynamic. Cool !

I have the following constructor function :

```
function Preferences () {

  this._preferences = {}

}

var obj = new Preferences()
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
>>> obj.something = 'value'
>>> this._preferences['something']
    'value'
```

That is setting the property of the `obj` does not actually set it's own property but that of `obj._preferences`. That is I want to **override** the default behavior.

Is it possible ?

**EDIT :** I want to achieve this for all property names i.e the name of the property to be set is not already known.

Comment: It sure is - have a look at [getters/setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Custom_Setters_and_Getters).

Comment: If you want to do with for specific property names, you can use `Object.defineProperty`. If you want to do this for all property names, you need an ES6 `Proxy`.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [Javascript overloading dot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569296/javascript-overloading-dot); you will need to use the `--harmony-proxies` command-line flag when starting Node

Comment: @apsillers , I guess using that would be not good, due to the support issues. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @black-perl I'm not sure what support issues you're concerned about -- do you need to do this in a browser client? Your question is tagged `[node.js]`, so I assumed you wanted to do this on the server (where you can always control what server version you run). Just make sure you're running a modern (i.e., more recent than 2013, maybe) installation of Node.js.

Comment: @apsillers, yeah sure !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Object.defineProperty(Preferences.prototype, 'something', {
  get: function(){
    return this._preferences.something;
  },
  set: function(value){
    this._preferences.something = value;
  }
});
```

should do it. It defines a property, 'something', using an accessor property instead of a data property, and will call the 'get' and 'set' functions to decide what do so when `.something` is accessed.

Comment: It requires the knowledge of property names before hand.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible at the moment. It's doable with ES6 proxies or [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) but those are brand new features that are not well supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION 1

Using Proxy object you can do something like this and handle runtime defined properties

```
function Preferences() {
  this._preferences = {};

  var prefProxy = new Proxy(this, {
    get: function(target, property) {  
      return property in target? 
              target[property]:
              target._preferences[property];
    }

    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
      if(property in target){
        target[property] = value;
      } else {
        target._preferences[property] = value;
      }
    }

  });


  return prefProxy;  
};
```

### SOLUTION 2

I can be wrong but i think what you are asking is solved returning `_preferences`

```
function Preferences () {

  this._preferences = {};

  return _preferences;
}

var obj = new Preferences()
```

### SOLUTION 3

Using getter and setter you can redirect the property to `_preferences`

```
function Preferences () {

  this._preferences = {}

  Object.defineProperty(Preferences.prototype, 'something', {
    get: function() {
        return this._preferences['something'];
    },
    set: function(value) {
       this._preferences['something'] = value; 
    }
  });


}

var obj = new Preferences()
```