# is JS able to overwrite Object's Getter method?

Tags: javascript

everyone:

as we all know, getting a nonexistent value from Object will got a "undefined", is there any way to throw an error instead of return a `undefined`?

for instance:

```
var a= {example:"example"};
//do something here

a.b  //error throw instead of "undefined"
```

thx very much for helping.

Comment: Looking at the above example, are you trying to initialize the property "b" on the object a with a value.

Comment: only in firefox can you catch unknown key access like that (methodmissing-style)

Answer (score 1):

Object.define property has a way to specify the get and set methods

look at the link below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Object class has a method "hasOwnProperty" which could also be used to check if a property exists or not before trying to access it

Comment: set and get method is for given keys, it still not able to throw an error when using `var v=  a.b` if b is not a key of a.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 comes with Proxy Objects which will help you overload the dot operator. What this means is that you can invoke a function when you retrieve a property. This will allow you to check if the property is defined and if it isn't "throw" an error. Hope this helps. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569296/javascript-overloading-dot/4569315#4569315)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above example, if you are you trying to initialize the property "b" on the object a with a value after "a" has been defined, then you could just as easily do the following:

```
var a= {example:"example"};
//do something here

a.b = 'some value';
a.b  //now an error is not throw
```

Most Objects can be re-defined even after they have been initialized. Properties and methods can be added and removed once objects have been initialized.
I say most, because it is possible to prevent objects from being extended/altered (using Object.preventExtension method).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions

Comment: sorry , i do not means to add a value or function for given object, instead, i want an error to be throw when i try to attach a "undefined" value in object.

Comment: If that's the case then as Praveen mentioned, you need to use Object.defineProperty and add your validation logic in the setter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: can i clone an Object class, and overwrite the dot operator(`.`)  by some way in ES5?

Comment: What do you mean by overwrite dot operator? Can you provide some sample code to demonstrate what it is that you are trying to achieve?