# How to automatically add intermediate structure to a nested Object (à la Python's defaultdict)?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

I would like to automatically add intermediate properties when creating a nested Object:

```js
let a = {}
a.hello.world = 1
```

This raises an error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'world' of undefined`) because `hello` does not exist.

In the Python world, there is a special type (an extension of `dict` = `Object` in JS) where the intermediate structure is built on the fly:

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.defaultdict(dict)
>>> a['hello']['world'] = 1
>>> a
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'hello': {'world': 1}})
```

**Is there such a mechanism or type in JavaScript?**

Comment: No, there is not. You can make your own of course.

Comment: @Pointy: how would I approach that? (the making of my own) - I will be glad to learn but my knowledge of JS is basic for now.

Comment: There are other questions about that on SO; people used to call it "object graph navigation".  Decide on a property access syntax and then split up the string appropriately and iterate through the object graph, property by property.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way seems to explicitly declare

`a.hello = {world:1}`

it seems even quicker than the python use of a **collections** library ...

**_ edit _**

Here is a workaround greatly inspired by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4569315/157247)

It is far from being clean (it creates complex objects and has surely performance issues) but it allows getter chaining

```js
function dict () {
  return new Proxy({}, {
    get: function (target, name, receiver) {
      if (!(name in target)) {
        target[name] = dict(); // for it to work on multiple levels
      };
      return target[name];
    }
  });
};

var a = dict();
a.hello.yes.yes.yo = 5 ;
console.log(a.hello.yes.yes.yo); // 5
console.log(a); // Proxy {hello: Proxy}
```

see this as a beginning rather than a solution ...

Comment: That would be a solution for a one-shot operation. This does not works when one has to first set `a.hello.world`, and somewhere else `a.hello.something`. The second operation with your method would overwrite the first one. If I need to keep track of that it will be ultimately easier to build the skeleton of the Object in advance (`a = {} ; a.hello = {}` and then use the full dotted form. I was looking for a factory-oriented solution like the one in Python.