# Pass JavaScript array to local variable by reference?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a JavaScript array inside a namespace like this:

```
app.collec.box = [];
```

and I have a function inside the same namespace like this:

```
app.init = function () {
    var box = this.collec.box;
    // ... code to modify box
};
```

I thought that setting a local variable equal to an object or object property was just a REFERENCE to the original, but it seems I am wrong, after changing the contents of the local `box` variable inside my function, `app.collec.box` does not change.

Please help, what am I doing wrong? how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT.** This is the complete code.

```
var app = {
    collec: {
        box: [],
        cache: []
    },

    init: function () {
        var box = this.collec.box;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'file.json',
            success: function (json) {
                // Map JSON array to box array using Underscore.js _()map
                box = _(json).map(function (o) {
                    return new Model(o);
                });
            }
        });
    }
};

app.init();
```

Comment: You've excluded relevant code from your question.

Comment: @patrick indeed. @VerizonW please include the snippet of code that actually causes app.init to be called.

Comment: You should look into getters and setters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies

Comment: This article may help you as well: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Answer (score 6, accepted):

References point to objects, not variables. `box` is not a reference to the variable `this.collec.box`; rather, `box` and `this.collec.box` are references to one specific object in memory. You can modify the properties of this object through either of these variables, but you can't use one variable to modify another variable.

If you want to modify what `this.collec.box` refers to, you either need to set it directly like this:

```
this.collec.box = ...;
```

or use a reference to the `this.collec` object and modify its `box` property:

```
var x = this.collec;
x.box = ...;
```

---

**Edit:** Maybe a couple of diagrams will make it easier to understand what's happening.

When you assign `box = this.collec.box`, this is what actually happens:

```
this.collec.box -----> (object) <----- box
```

Both the variables point to the same object in memory, but in no way does `box` actually refer to the `this.collec.box` variable.

What you are expecting would work if this happened:

```
box -----> this.collec.box -----> (object)
```

but this doesn't happen.

Comment: This answer contains incorrect information. The code posted above will work as the OP expects, *if* app.init is called in a way such that `this` actually refers to `app.init` (for example, simply calling `app.init()`.

Comment: @Jason: What are you talking about? Clearly this answer anticipates `this` referring to `app`. OP hasn't shown *what* he's doing with `box`.

Comment: @Jason LeBrun: As I understand the question, the OP is trying to do `box = ...` inside the function and is asking why this change doesn't reflect in `this.collec.box`.

Comment: No, `this` absolutely does not have to refer to app, depending on the context in which `app.init` is called. Arrays variables are indeed references, `var anarray = someOtherArray` does not create a copy of `someOtherArray,` it creates another variable which will modify `someOtherArray` if it's used. Run this in a JS console and you'll see that it works: `var o = {}; o.box =[]; o.init = function() { var l = this.box; l[0] = 'foo'; }; o.init(); console.log(o.box[0]);`

Comment: @Jason LeBrun: I think you're missing the point of this answer. Of course `l[0] = 'foo'` will work, but will `l = 10` change the value of `o.box`? No, and that's what I said.

Comment: @Jason: As I said, this answer *anticipates* `this` referring to `app`. As such, the information in this answer is correct. Just because you're assuming that `this` is not referring to `app` doesn't make this answer wrong. There simply isn't enough info in the question to determine what the problem is.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I made the assumption that "code to modify box" implied using array mutator functions, not actually assigning to box again. I guess more code in the original question would clear this up right away.

Comment: On the bright side, I think we've collectively covered about 90% of the potential issues he could be having ;-)

Comment: Just saw his edit, and you have indeed nailed his problem. If you make any edit to your answer, I can upvote it. :-)

Comment: Thanks! this works, however I don't understand why box and this.collec.box are both references

Comment: @VerizonW: I've updated the answer and I hope it's somewhat easier to understand now.

Comment: @Jason: I just edited the answer, so you can remove the downvote if you want. :)

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing should work.

I think your problem is with the keyword *this* (although I can't be certain without seeing more of your code).  *this* is likely referring to the function (app.init) itself, not *app*.

To troubleshoot try changing ...

var box = this.collec.box;

... to ...

var box = app.collec.box;

**[EDIT]**

After seeing more of your code, my answer still stands: just replace *this* with *app*.

You should also put that line (var box = app.collec.box;) inside the callback function.  I don't think the callback will keep the reference to box as it is an async call.

Comment: That won't help in this case, Casablanca's answer is the one the OP needs.

Comment: Thanks, but changing it to app.collec.box didn't solve the problem

Comment: No worries.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

since javascript is lexically scoped, the `this` keyword will be referencing the anonymous function instead of the actual `app` keyword, like what @rick roth is saying.  you should make a closure and have something like this outside of your anonymous function:

```
var ns = this;
```

and then you would do

```
ns.collec.box = [];
```

`ns` can be whatever you want, but then within `app.init`, you would reference the array like so:

```
app.init = function () {
    var box = ns.collec.box;
    // ... code to modify box
};
```

so then, as long as your closure is set up correctly, anything pointing to `ns`, will be referenced correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
app.init = function (box) {
    // ... code to modify box
};

app.init(this.collec.box);
```

Comment: What is the value of `this` that you're using in the argument sent to `init`?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably passing app.init in such a way that the context of app is being lost. When you do something like div.onclick = app.init, or setTimeout(app.init, 1000), when app.init finally gets called back, `this` will *not* point to `app`, it will point to `div` or `window` respectively.

If you need to assign an object's method as a callback, use a closure. For example:

`div.onclick = function() { app.init() };`

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch:

You could be using one of the Array instance methods that return a new array instance instead of modifying the original array. Are you by any chance using either `concat`, `join` or `slice`? These are accessors, not mutators.

Also:

If you're modifying the `box` local variable, make sure you assign it back when you're done:

```
var box = this.collec.box;
// ... code to modify box
this.collec.box = box;
```