# JavaScript variables giving the correct value when stepped through using the console, but not otherwise

Tags: javascript, variables, setter

I have a variable in a JavaScript constructor that appears to be set to the correct value when stepped through using breakpoints.  However, when run without breakpoints, the variable (supposed to be an array that I give it), comes up as an empty array in the console. I don't know whether or not using the get/set property of prototype, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies/813332#813332).  Also-- I'm working in webkit, so if someone could help explain to me why it isn't working there, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

```
function Box(inElement){
    var self = this;
    this.element = inElement;
    this.boxes = (function () {
        var boxes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < inElement.childNodes.length; ++i) {
            if (3 !== inElement.childNodes[i].nodeType) {
                boxes.push(inElement.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
        return boxes;
    })();
    this.rotation = [-40,-20,0,20,40];
}

Box.prototype = 
{   
    get rotation(){
    return this._rotation;
    },

    set rotation(rotArray){

        console.log('rotArray');
        console.log(rotArray);

        var thisrot;
        this._rotation = rotArray;
        for(var i=0; i<this.boxes.length; i++){
            thisrot = rotArray.shift();
            this.boxes[i].style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(' + thisrot + 'deg) translateZ(170px)';
        } 
    }
}

function loaded()
{
    new Box(document.getElementById('area'));
}

window.addEventListener('load',loaded, true);
```

So, after some fiddling, I discovered that boxes.push(inElement.childnodes[i] is the problematic line.  When commented out, the value comes out as expected.

Comment: Smells like a race condition. Can you post some code?

Comment: This might be a scope issue - could you post your code please?

Comment: Added a code sample, sorry guys.

Comment: which variable is the problematic one? rotation, when set through setter?

Comment: Well, rotArray is returning [], which I expect to be [-40,-20,0,20,40] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing all elements from your array in the loop inside of `set rotation` using `shift`. Arrays are passed by reference in JavaScript, not by value. If you want to create a copy of your array, you will have to use `Array.slice`:

```
this._rotation = rotArray.slice();
```