# Is it possible to make a JavasScript function act as if it was a string, no ()

Tags: javascript, string, function

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

```
var data = 'one';
function fnc(){
    this.out = function(){
        return data;
    }
}
var instance = new fnc();

alert(instance.out);
data = 'two';
alert(instance.out);

// I know that this would achieve that, but that's not what I would like to know.

alert(instance.out());
data = 'two';
alert(instance.out());
```

**Update:**

The object which fnc is supposed to represent is actually a Sarissa dom document. Here is a more elaborate version of fnc(), dom_doc(). The accepted answer below has been integrated into the function below.

```
function get_doc(dom_node) {
    var doc;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        doc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
        doc.loadXML(document.getElementById(dom_node).text);
    }
    else {
        doc = Sarissa.getDomDocument();
        doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(document.getElementById(dom_node).textContent, "text/xml");
        // runs XSLTProcessor in modern browsers as if it was trasformNode
        doc.transformNode = function (stylesheet) {
            var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
            processor.importStylesheet(stylesheet);
            return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(processor.transformToDocument(this));
        }

        // allows modern browsers to extract xml the way the legacy IEs did
        var getXML = {};
        getXML.toString = function(){
            return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);
        };
        doc.xml = getXML;
    }
    return doc;
}
```

**Demo:** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh6du/1/)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It's called *getter*s.

Comment: Not the best dupe, but I found [Javascript getters and setters for dummies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies)

Comment: @Bergi yep, thank you, I was unaware of getters

Comment: @Bergi Do dupes get removed? If so, idk if that's a great idea, without knowing the word "getter" I spent far too much time Googling around without much luck.

Comment: @Serhiy Usually, questions closed as duplicates are kept as signposts for people coming to them via Google.

Comment: @Jari I'm working with a legacy app, XML data islands, and Sarissa. I set up as just a quick sample so as to not get into...  doc.xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm not sure this is still a duplicate of getters. The non getter solution worked best for me.

Comment: @Serhiy There is nothing in the code at the jsfiddle mentioning `dom_doc()` or `fnc`. Also, please post the code here so the context is clearer. Where is the code that is using the result of `get_doc()?`

Comment: @Serhiy I have a feeling that bfavaretoo's suggestion didn't work because you're using IE8? In IE 8 you can only add getters to DOM nodes http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.defineProperty

Comment: @JuanMendes No actually Chrome v26, for IE I'm just using ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0"), also update the question from JS fiddle stuff

Comment: @Serhiy Now that I'm seeing your actual code, why not just `doc.xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);`?

Comment: @bfavaretto The xml is manipulated via setAttribute and such. This is what I had first tried and noticed that the changes are not reflected, only the original xml string is returned.

Comment: @Serhiy Can you post the code that is calling `get_doc(dom_node)`? I still don't understand why you can't use getters

Comment: @JuanMendes what do I care I got my answer... haha j/k, here's the fiddle to illustrate what's going on. I couldn't get getters nor prototype to work in this context http://jsfiddle.net/Sh6du/1/

Comment: @bfavaretto I made an example of my last comment to you in this fiddle, just uncomment line 23 http://jsfiddle.net/Sh6du/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/s8PEt/)***

These types of workarounds really bypass convention though. It should not be that much of a hamper to simply use `()` on your functions. Using `()` is expected, readable, best practice, and the industry standard.

Not sure why [`smartcaveman`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344211/smartcaveman) decided to remove his answer of using `toString` but that is a viable approach although somewhat hackish.

```
var data = 'one';
function fnc(){
 var getData = {};
 getData.toString = function(){
   return data;
 };
 this.out = getData;
}

var instance = new fnc();

alert(instance.out);//one
data = 'two';
alert(instance.out);//two

var s = instance.out;
alert(s);//two
```

Comment: I hope it wasn't my fault for going nope when his solution didn't work. This however is exactly what I need, and changed the answer to this one, as the other two methods didn't quite work within the context of the actual situation.

Comment: smartcaveman's answer only works if what you are using is automatically calling `toString()` for you, like `alert`. It's not what the OP is asking

Comment: I disagree that the standard is using a method. JavaScript always had property getter/setters, it's just we (JS developers) couldn't create our own. Simplest example is a setter like `document.cookie="..."`, it doesn't just set a property, it calls a method under the hood.

Comment: OP here, here is the context in which this is the only answer that worked, and as to why I accepted this answer over the others, in case anyone is interested. http://jsfiddle.net/kqFP5/

Comment: @Serhiy You may be the OP, but this is not the answer to the question you asked, it's the workaround for the problem you're facing, two different things. This question should be useful to everyone, not just the problem you were trying to solve. That's the spirit of Stack Overflow. It's also not clear what your jsfiddle is proving

Comment: @JuanMendes It's the answer with the code that most resembles the language in the title of the question. It's also the one that worked for my use case. It may be a work around, but it does exactly what I thought I asked. I didn't ask for a getter or prototype lesson... I know I'm a dummy... :P

Comment: @Serhiy I'm just explaining to you that the spirit of SO is not to fix your problem specifically, but to answer the question in a way that is useful to others. Now others may think this is the right solution, but it's only right for your case

Comment: @JuanMendes - I believe you are misrepresenting the "spirit" when you are making these statements. Please read this post on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/178816 and make a post on meta with regards to your issue on the "spirit of SO" before you take on the full mantle of what stackoverflow is or isn't or begin dictating what the OP should or should not accept. Note the part which says: "The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally."

Comment: @JuanMendes good call, I'll edit the question to provide the context as well. I just figured boiling the problem down made it easier to digest. I may have boiled it down too much.

Comment: @TravisJ Serhiy understood what I meant: the question and answer are out of balance, fixing the question is the right thing to do. From the same post "Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is really good practice. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another comes in, uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact a bad hack." This isn't a bad hack, but it's still a workaround. Without context from the OP, it's unclear why they can't just use getters

Answer (score 9):

You seem to be talking about a *getter* method. If that's what you mean, you can use this:

```
var data = 'one';
function fnc(){
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'out', {
        get : function(){ return data; }
    });
}
var instance = new fnc();

alert(instance.out);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zztYd/1

This is not compatible with older browsers (see the compatibility table at the bottom of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)).

Also, it's a little weird to use a getter to fetch a global variable. Usually you use that to get the value of a private variable on your instance object, and in that case you could only modify it with a corresponding setter.

Comment: Don't you want your `defineProperty` call within the constructor?

Comment: Why not put the property definition *inside* the constructor, just as the OP had it?

Comment: @Serhiy There's also the literal syntax `fnc.prototype = { get x() function(){return data}}` http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/zztYd/2/

Comment: @JuanMendes But that's non-standard, isn't it?

Comment: Is a getter the only way to implement this?

Comment: @TravisJ If you don't want the calling parentheses, yes.

Comment: @bfavaretto https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get says it's in ECMAScript5 and Supported by IE9+/Firefox1.8.1+/Chrome/Opera9.5+/Safari3+

Comment: Nit: Getters make it possible for a *property* that evaluates to a function - but not for a general *function* - to be "invoked without ()"

Comment: @JuanMendes - There is nothing wrong per say, although some people must support ie8+, so that would be the major reason I asked.

Comment: @JuanMendes Getters and setters are part of ES5, but `get` as an operator is a Mozilla thing (it's not in the ES5 spec, or at least I couldn't find it).

Comment: @user2246674 You still need IE9 to use `Object.defineProperty` so it's the same problem.

Comment: @bfavaretto Look at page 65 http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @JuanMendes Ah, thanks! So it's not an operator as MDN states.

Answer (score 4):

The alternative to [bfavaretto's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472390/227299) solution is to use the literal syntax for an object. Has almost the same level of support as `Object.defineProperty()`.

Also, you should call `Object.defineProperty` only once, not with every instantiation.

I'm also going to provide a more realistic example, that is, the property gets calculated, instead of just referencing a global.

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/zztYd/3/

```
function Pair(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

Pair.prototype = {
    get sum(){ 
        return this.a + this.b; 
    }
};

var pair = new Pair(1,2);
alert(pair.sum);
pair.a = 5;
alert(pair.sum);
```

The benefit of this is that you can change the implementation to be storage instead of calculation and you won't have to change how it's called.

```
function Pair(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.sum = a + b;
}

Pair.prototype = {
    setA: function(a){ 
        this.a  = a;
        this.sum = this.a + this.b; 
    }
};

var pair = new Pair(1,2);
alert(pair.sum);
pair.setA(5);
alert(pair.sum);
```

Notice that you do have to now call `setA` so that sum can be recalculated. Or you could use a setter.

```
function Pair(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.sum = a + b;
}

Pair.prototype = {
    set a(a) {
        this.a  = a;
        this.sum = this.a + this.b; 
    }
};

var pair = new Pair(1,2);
alert(pair.sum);
pair.a = 5;
alert(pair.sum);
```

Comment: +1 for an actually useful example of a getter - and for that comment with the page number on the ecma spec :) Just one thing: this syntax is clearly simpler, but Object.defineProperty doesn't necessarily have to be called with every instantiation; it could be used on the constructor's prototype just like you did here.

Comment: @bfavaretto Fixed the text so it doesn't imply that `Object.defineProperty` doesn't necessarily have to be called with every instantiation