# automatic getter and setter(with validation) in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am building a javascript library where I have to create a log of classes and most of them have a lot of properties which have to make public for the user.

For example:

```
function Person(name,age){

}
```

Now I want to create the getter and setter for properties (name and age).

Nornall, I have to add these methods to `Person.prototype`:

```
Person.prototype.getName=function(){}
Person.prototype.setName=function(x){
  //check if x is typeof String
}
Person.prototype.getAge=function(){}
Person.prototype.setAge=function(x){
  //check if x is typeof Number
}
```

This will result in two many lines of repeated codes.

So I wonder if I can call a method like this:

```
makeThesePropertiesPublic(Person,{
  name:"string",
  age:"number"
});
```

Then I can call this:

```
var p=new Person("xx",1);
p.getName();
p.getAge();
.......
```

Is there a out-of-box method to implement this?

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can't define the getter and setter functions on the `prototype` because they need to be able to access `name` and `age` which are only accessible inside the constructor. Hence you would need to define the getter and setter functions inside the constructor.

I would do this:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    var private = {
        name: name,
        age: age
    };

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        name: getAccessor(private, "name", "String"),
        age: getAccessor(private, "age", "Number")
    });
}

function getAccessor(obj, key, type) {
    return {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        get: function () {
            return obj[key];
        },
        set: function (value) {
            if (typeOf(value) === type)
                obj[key] = value;
        }
    };
}

function typeOf(value) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1);
}
```

Now you can access create a `Person` and access their `name` and `age` properties as follows:

```
var person = new Person("Aadit M Shah", 20);

person.name = 0;       // it won't set the name
person.age = "twenty"; // it won't set the age

alert(person.name);
alert(person.age);
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aVM2J/

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
function Person(n, a) {

    var name = n;
    var age = a;

    var person = {};
    person.getName = function () {
         return name
    }

    person.getAge = function () {
         return age;
    }


    return person;
}
var p = Person("jon",22);
console.log(p.getName());//jon
```