# Getters and settings in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to understand why do we use getters and setters in javascript? When should it be used.

I know the general concept of getters and setters.

For example:

```
    var obj = new Object();
    obj['abc'] = "something"; //setting an object.
    console.log(obj['abc']); //getting
```

If a similar mechanism is achieved using the above code, when do we need to use getters and setters?

Can someone explain?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the MDN docs on Javascript Objects. It should go over a number of common use cases such as yours: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getters and setters for dummies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies)

Comment: Getters and setters are recomended in JavaScript when using Class notation (syntaxic sugar).
Getters and setters are public methods for reading and writing private properties.
Hence, if you don't emulate private members there's no need to implement getters and setters.