# Is it possible to assign a value to an object to trigger an action/method?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
location = "http://www.mozilla.org";
```

You assign a string to [a Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to navigate to a new page.

Can it also be done with ordinary Javascript object?

The first method that comes to mind is `setter`, but it requires specifying the property name as Object.property.

The second method may be assignment overload, but it seems no such thing in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use
[Object.watch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) property.
But as it is not supported in all browsers u need a
[Polyfill](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583) to be added to your file.
Apart from these readymade functions you can write your own function using setTimeout() or [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) where you can check the specific property of the function in consecutive threads.

Example :

```
    var threadCheck = requestAnimationFrame ||
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 16);
    },

    oldProperty = {},

    watchFunction = function (obj, objProp) {
    var len = objProp.length,
        prop,
        i;
    for (i= 0; i < len; i++) {
        prop = objProp[i];
        oldProperty[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
    checkFunction();
},

checkFunction = function () {
    var prop;
    for (prop in oldProperty) {
        if (oldProperty[prop] !== obj[prop]) {
            executeFunction();
            oldProperty[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }
    threadCheck(checkFunction);
},

executeFunction = function () {
    console.log('changed')
},

obj = {
    propertyA : function() {},
    propertyB : 'check',
    propertyC : {
        dummy : 'xyz'
    },
    propertyD : 999
};

watchFunction(obj, ['propertyA', 'propertyB', 'propertyC', 'propertyD']);
```

Result(running the given code in the console of chrome browser, it's just a prototype, there are many scopes of improvements. Also unwatch() function has to be implemented):

```
obj.propertyA = function(){}
(){}
VM1016:35 changed
obj.propertyB = 'check'
"check"
obj.propertyB = 'check1'
"check1"
VM1016:35 changed
obj.propertyB = 'check1'
"check1"
obj.propertyB = 'check2'
"check2"
VM1016:35 changed
obj.propertyA = 'check2'
"check2"
VM1016:35 changed
obj.propertyA = function(){}
(){}
VM1016:35 changed
obj.propertyD = 999
999
obj.propertyD = 99
99
VM1016:35 changed
obj.propertyD = 991
991
VM1016:35 changed
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes by defining a property.

```
var test = function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
};

var d = Date.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(d, "year", {
    get: function () { return this.getFullYear() },
    set: function (y) { test(y); }
});

d.year = 2016;
```

→

```
Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, "foo", {
    get: function () { return 'hi' },
    set: function (y) { alert('hi' + y); }
});

foo = 2016;
```

[Stackoverflow - Javascript getters and setters for dummies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies)

[Mozilla - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

[Mozilla - Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to assign something to an object and automatically trigger an action method in JavaScript. "location" is actually a property of window object. The getter of the location property returns an object "Location" that has "href" and some other properties and methods. The setter of the location property takes a string and set it internally to "href" property of "Location" object. You can implement something like this using JavaScript getter and setter yourself. See this for reference: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/.
Hope this make sense.

Comment: It is always possible though not advisable.

Comment: @kingshuk bask: If you assign something to an object variable it will overwrite the original object variable, how would that trigger an action method?

Comment: You need to have helper functions that will check at successive threads whether the current and previous value of the property of an object are same or different. @deepak bhatia

Comment: @kingshukbasak `successive threads whether the current and previous value of the property of an object are same or different.` This sounds interesting. Any example?

Comment: @J.Joe  - I have given an implementation example without using any advanced JS features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. ES5 introduced the concept of setters and getters to close the gap between APIs like `window.location` and `element.innerHTML` and what you can do in javascript.

Setters and getters can be defined directly in an object literal:

```
var myobj = {
  set foo (str) {
    // execute a function
  },
  get foo () {
    // execute a function
  }
}
```

Notice the syntax - there's no `:` after the keywords `set` and `get` to differentiate them from regular keys `"set"` and `"get"`.

With the declaration above, doing either:

```
myobj.foo = somevalue;
```

or
    somevar = myobj.foo;

will trigger the respective `set` and `get` functions.

Alternatively, if you already have an object, you may add a property with a setter and getter using `Object. defineProperty()`:

```
Object.defineProperty(myobj, "bar", {
    get: function () {
      // execute a function
    },
    set: function (y) {
      // execute a function
    }
});
```

Now doing `myobj.bar = x` will call the setter function for `bar`.

---

See the following for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get