# Allow write access to certain keys only

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a list of objects which look like this when they are created:

```
{
  owner: "<user uid>",
  pending: true,
  origin: { ... },
  destination: { ... },
  fare: { ... },
  driver: {
    user: null,
    ...
  }
}
```

I need to write rules such that:

1. Anyone can insert a new object
2. Anyone can read objects
3. Anyone can claim an object, by setting `pending: false`, and `driver.user: <their uid>`. They should only have write permission on `pending` and `driver.*`
4. Once an object has been claimed, no one else should be able to modify it except the original `owner`, and `driver.user` (`driver.user` should only be able to modify `pending` and `driver.*`)

Is this possible, and if so what would these rules look like?

---

This is not a duplicate, it has nothing to do with Getters or Setters. This is a question about Firebase Rules - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

Comment: Have a look at using [getters and setters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies). You can apply some access validation in them.

Comment: @Cerbrus These only provide client-side validation. I need these rules on Firebase, or anyone could create a client without validation and do whatever they want

Comment: So, why did you tag this with JavaScript then?

Comment: I'm using the Javascript library for Firebase

Comment: ... And you can just use getters / setters in there, right? I mean, the JS code you write just gets compiled into a native app in the end, not? What other language are you working in if JS isn't it?

Comment: It does get compiled into a native app, however if the rules aren't configured with Firebase there's nothing to stop anyone decompiling the app, finding the connection information and modifying data with no restrictions.

Comment: @Cerbrus Firebase has it's own server side rules that secure the data on the server side. The rules are used to set read/write access to particular nodes at the server level. It's not so much a Javascript question but the tag does let us know the OP's platform. OP: we really need to see a snippet of the exact Firebase structure - Firebase Console->Three dots on right->export JSON and include that in the question. You should also post the rules you've tried so far.