# Setter in javascript

Tags: javascript, setter

Why is person1's 'name' property is 'undefined' while person2's 'name' property has a value?

```js
    const person1 = {
        set name(newName) {
            console.log(newName)
        }
    }
    
    const person2 = {}
    Object.assign(person2, person1)
    
    person1.name = 'x'  
    // logs "x"
    
    person2.name = 'z' 
    // doesnt log anything
    
    console.log("Person1", person1)
    // "Person1" Object {
    //   name: undefined
    // }
    
    console.log("Person2", person2)
    // "Person2" Object {
    //   name: "z"
    // }
```

Link to CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmoMzj?editors=1112

Comment: Your setter has to actually set something to store the value. Then you have no getter for `name`. `Object.assign()` makes shallow copy so the setter is gone in person2. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getters and setters for dummies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies)

Comment: `Why is person1's 'name' property is 'undefined' while person2's 'name' property has a value?` simply because your setters isn't doing anything just logging in the value,  and `Object.assign()` do invoke getters and setters it doesn't create new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're observing is the result of the default behaviour of `Object.assign()`.

#### 1. person1's 'name' property is 'undefined'

If the property is not defined in the object and only a setter is defined, any attempt to access the property directly will return `undefined`. You should either define the property `name` in `person1` or it's getter to access it as `person1.name`.

That is why when you log `person1`, `name` is `undefined`.

**`person1.name` is returning undefined because `person1` only has a `setter` and no `getter`**

#### 2. person2's 'name' property has a value

When these two lines are executed,

```
const person2 = {}
Object.assign(person2, person1)
```

**getters** and **setters** are not copied in `Object.assign()` but they are invoked and new properties are created in the process. Since `set name(newName)` doesn't have an equivalent `getter` or the property `name` in `person1`, the `name` property in `person2` is assigned `undefined` during `Object.assign()`. So this will be your `person2` at the end of `Object.assign()`

```
person2 = { name: undefined };
```

without any getter or setter.

And, when you invoke this line

```
person2.name = 'z'
```

the name property is assigned the value `z`.

**`person2.name` is returning the value because `person2` doesn't have a getter or setter and just returns the assigned value.**

Comment: Good walk through of why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

As in the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Defining_a_setter_on_new_objects_in_object_initializers) demonstrated in the docs, it states that:

> Note that `name` is not defined and any attempts to access it will result in undefined.

`name` is used in the preceding quote to state property setter `name` as in your example.

So, you have define the getter to return it's result. And I suggest you to follow the example provided on docs itself.

Comment: ah, had something on mind. just  got it and updated. thanks.