# Why setter with set keyword and function expressed in ES5 throws syntax error?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

Why defining a `setter` throws syntax error when the function is expressed the ES5 way but works when expressed in ES6.

**Setter with ES5 syntax(Doesn't work)**

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "",
  set setLanguage: function(val) {
     this.language = val    
  },
  get getLanguage() {
     return this.language   
  }     
}

person.setLanguage = 'EN'
person.getLanguage
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`
```

**Setter with ES6 syntax (Works)**

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "",
  set setLanguage(val) {
     this.language = val    
  },
  get getLanguage() {
     return this.language   
  }     
}

person.setLanguage = 'EN'
person.getLanguage
```

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be `set setLanguage(val) {
     this.language = val    
  }` in your first code example ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/getters-setters-for-dummies I'm not marking it as a duplicate, but it's really really close ;)

Comment: @CodeManiac seems that OP thinks that this syntax is ES6

Comment: Why would you use this naming convention anyway? Wouldn't it be more natural to have `lang: '', get language() { return this.lang; }, set language(val) { this.lang = val; }`? Then your code could just do `person.language = 'en';` and `var lang = person.language;`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is not ES6 specific, it's valid **ES5** syntax:

```
set setLanguage(val) {
    this.language = val;    
},
```

From [Object Initialiser's specification (ES5)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)

> *PropertyAssignment* :
>    *PropertyName* : *AssignmentExpression*
>    **get** *PropertyName* ( ) { *FunctionBody* }
>    **set** *PropertyName* ( *PropertySetParameterList* ) { *FunctionBody* }

As you can see, there's a `:` after *PropertyName*, but there's no `:` or `function` in getter or setter

**Update:**

You propably confused concepts of *computed property names* and *getters/setters*

ES6 [introduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Specifications) computed property names, so you can do this (this snippet propably won't work in older browsers, like IE):

```js
const person = {
  language: "",
  setLanguage(val){
    this.language = val;
  },
  getLanguage(){
    return this.language;
  }
}

person.setLanguage("EN");

console.log("person.language", person.language);
console.log("person.getLanguage()",person.getLanguage())
```

Note lack of `set` or `get` keywords and that you have to call `person.setLanguage("EN");` instead of `person.setLanguage = "EN";`

In ES5 you'll have to (change `const` to `var` and) use:

```
setLanguage: function(val) {
    this.language = val;    
},
getLanguage: function() {
    return this.language;    
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining method properly in your object read this --> [**Method definitions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) also this [**Defining getters and setters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

```js
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "",
  set setLanguage(val) {
     this.language = val    
  },
  get getLanguage() {
     return this.language   
  }     
}

person.setLanguage = 'EN'
console.log(person.getLanguage)
```