# When do we need to use "get" key word in JavaScript OOP

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6, get

I am refreshing my memory with OOP in JavaScript and I get a bit confused. I just pick one of my project and try to convert it to OOP. Is 'get' key word really important? Let see the code below:

```
class Cipher {
    constructor (str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    normalizedPlainText() {
        return this.str.replace(/\W/g,'').toLowerCase();
    }

    size() {
        return this.normalizedPlainText(this.str).length;
    }

    isValid() {
        if ( this.size(this.str) >= 50 ) return true;
    }

    squareRoot() {
        return parseInt(Math.sqrt(this.size((this.str))));
    }

    nbrRows() {
        return this.squareRoot(this.str);
    }

    get nbrCols() {
        if ( Math.pow(this.squareRoot(this.str), 2) === this.size(this.str)) return this.squareRoot(this.str);
        else return this.squareRoot(this.str) + 1;
    }
}



    const cipher = new Cipher('Your description gives people the information they need to help you answer your question##8.');
    console.log('sqrt '+cipher.squareRoot())
    console.log('Nbr rows ' + cipher.nbrRows()) //good output
    console.log('Nbr cols ' + cipher.nbrCols) // good output too
```

When designing my program I was wondering if I could use 'get' or not. So O did try as you can see on get nbrCols(). If I put get nbrRows() and call it `cipher.nbrRows()` I get an error unless I change the way I call it as this `cipher.nbrRows`.
So the conclusion I have is this: it's up to you. If you use 'get' call it without () or I you don't use it call it with ().
Am I wrong or do I miss something?

Comment: You are correct, you can use `get col()` and then call the function as if it’s a variable. You can also just create a function `getCol()`. That way it’s more clear that a function is being used. It’s up to you what you prefer but I think functions are more readable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/getters-setters-for-dummies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the get syntax, you're adding a getter to the object, these were introduced in ES5 (2009).

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

You could of course add an explicit getProperty function instead of using the getter.

You don't use parenthesis when accessing a getter,

Whichever technique you use is up to you, each has its own advantages,

For example:

```js
let person = { 
   _age: 42,
   get age() { 
       console.log("getter called!");
       return this._age;
   },
   set age(age) {
       console.log("setter called!");
       this._age = age; 
   },
   getAge() {
       return this._age; 
   }
}

console.log("Age: ", person.age);
console.log("Age (using getAge()): ", person.getAge());

// Assign age using setter 
person.age = 21;
console.log("Age (after set): ", person.age);
```

Answer (score 1):

> It's up to you. If you use `get` call it without `()` or if you don't use `get` call it with `()`.

Yes, exactly. You should use getter if want the value to be accessed like it was a data property, and only when the computation doesn't mutate your instance.