# es6 javascript setter function outside constuction

Tags: javascript

is it possible to call the setter function outside the constructor class?

i.e. i have the following class

```
class example {
  constructor() {
    this._partner = 0;
   }
   get partner() {
    return this._partner;
   }

  set partner(id) {
    this._partner = id;
  }
}
```

when i call

```
friends = new example();
freinds.partner(75);
```

i see the follwing error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: example.partner is not a function
```

Comment: It's just `freinds.partner`

Comment: but i want to set the partner name

Comment: It's not a function. You treat it as a regular property. `freinds.partner = 75`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getters \ setters for dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/getters-setters-for-dummies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invoke a setter/getter, it has to *look* from the outside as if you're directly setting or retrieving a property on the object (not calling a function):

```js
class example {
  constructor() {
    this._partner = 0;
   }
   get partner() {
    console.log('getter running');
    return this._partner;
   }

  set partner(id) {
    console.log('setter running');
    this._partner = id;
  }
}

friends = new example();
console.log('about to assign to .partner');
friends.partner = 75;
console.log('about to retrieve .partner');
console.log(friends.partner);
```

Note that the parameter that the setter sees is the value that looks like got "assigned" to the property outside.

Answer (score 0):

These setter and getter allow you to use the properties directly (without using the parenthesis)

```
friends.partner = 75;
```